# HTTP GET Request with complex parameters

Tags: http, spring-mvc, url, get

For some reason I need to perform some GET requests with a list of parameters that are duet of quantities and a flag.

For example I need my URL to contains this list :

```
quantities[0] = {100, false};
quantities[1] = {150, true};
quantities[2] = {25, true};
quantities[3] = {30, false};
```

Should the URL looks like this :

```
http://myhost/check?{quantity=100&flag=false}&{quantity=150&flag=true}&{quantity=25&flag=true}&{quantity=30&flag=true}
```

Comment: it can look however you want it to look. the question boils down to: what does the code handling this url expect to receive?

Comment: The backend is written in java using Spring MVC and the signature of the handling method would looks like `public Result handleQuantities(@RequestParameter List<Quantity> quantities)`

Comment: then you'll need to mod that. query strings are `key=value` pairs, and you'd en d up with (key)`{quantity` = (value)`100`, plus a whole bunch of duplicate `flag=falsse` k/v pairs.

Comment: Can you not have it as `http://myhost/check?quantity=100,150,25&flag=false,true,true` and pair `quantity[0]` with `flag[0]` and so on? I say this with no experience or use of SpringMVC.

Comment: I'm new to SpringMVC too, so I was wondering how to pair `quantity` and `flag`. Thanks for your answers I'll try out two separate lists.